# 64 bit pci video card on 32 bit pci slot

Tags: graphics-card, pci

I am going to install nvidia geforce gt 730 GDDR5. It is a 64 bit video card. But I think I  have a 32 bit pciex16 slot(See the image). My question is, can 128 bit and 64 bit video cards fit on 32 bit pci slot? 
[image: The black slot is 3.3V pciex16 slot 32 bit]

Comment: You might clean it while you've got it open, too. Looks like it's been for a ride round a cement factory :/

Comment: I know, will clean it soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCI-express slots are not "64 bit" or "128 bit". They have varying numbers of *lanes*. The more lanes, the faster the interface, but there is not a "bit width" limitation with fewer lanes.

The longer black slot in your picture appears to be an x16 slot, i.e. 16 lanes, which is the largest in anything like common use. Your GTI 730 DDR5 should work fine in that slot.

The "64 bit" or "128 bit" designation for your video card has to do with its internal architecture (specifically the interface between the GPU and the card's onboard memory), not the slot it plugs into.

PCIe is a serial protocol; the bits come in sequence in a "lane". Even a PCIe x1 slot can support 64-bit addresses. PCIe communication is in the form of "transport packets" that allow for either 32- or 64-bit addresses, and 32-bit data fields. See a much more complete description here:  http://xillybus.com/tutorials/pci-express-tlp-pcie-primer-tutorial-guide-1

The two white slots in the OP's picture are of course conventional PCI, which is 32 bits wide.

Answer (score -1):

How did you come to the conclusion that the slot was 32 bit? As far as I know all PCIe slots are x64 by default, that's what gives them one of their advantages over older PCI. There is always the possibility of "just try it" and if the PC doesn't post with the​ new GPU or it doesn't work in some way you'll know.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob. I came to such a conclusion by seeing this picture. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4R1PCS61woic2NfLWRJQk15MWM The first slot in the pic was similar to that. That's why, you see...

Comment: Yeah the longer sockets are x64, as yours is in the picture. I think it will work fine

Comment: No, the graphic linked by S.S is for conventional PCI (33 MHz, 32 bits) and its wider, but still parallel, variations. Not PCIe. PCIe slots are never "x64" (or x32 either). The physical length of a PCIe slot has _nothing to do_ with the bit width it supports, only with the number of lanes. Additional lanes don't allow more bits; they just make things faster.

Comment: Yeah I can't read apparently, and yeah the slot length doesn't matter of course :p.

Comment: I may bit off topic here,  how do i know whether the slot is 1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: Really depends on the age of your motherboard, whether it has support for the newer standards. Some motherboard manufacturers label the different slots to show what standard and PCIe width they are. Otherwise you will be able to find out in the BIOs most likely.

Comment: @Jamie what do you mean by SS?

Comment: Your initials. From "S.Srihari"

Comment: Regarding PCIe version: your motherboard's manual, or specs from the manufacturer's web site, will tell you. All the PCIe slots on a given motherboard will be of the same version, as this is determined by the chipset. All PCIe versions are "generally" inter-compatible, particularly for older-version cards in a newer-version slot; there may be power issues with PCIe 2.1 cards in PCIe 1.0, 1.0a, or 1.1 slots.